# Should questions that asks for behavior in a specific usage be considered a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

For example [Is an undefined variable in default argument bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733668/3196468) has been marked as a duplicate of [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c)

If the question is asking for clarification of the behavior in the second question is it still a duplicate?

Would it have been better to ask it as comment in the original question?

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but it sounds like you're looking for the definition of the behavior of an undefined behavior... Also, asking if something is "bad" can look like asking for opinions, which is something SO isn't really geared for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is perfectly fine to close special case question as duplicate of more generic one.

Your question (ignoring opinion based "is it bad" part) is essentially asking whether particular case is undefined behavior - duplicate is perfect way to say "yes" for any future visitors.

Overall you did provide reasonable explanation why you think it may not be the same behavior as general question and provided clear code sample. The only thing really missing are links to existing questions you've found while researching the question, especially if you think you could have asked comment on existing question instead.

I would not ask comment on existing question in such case - you will not be able to provide any details/code in comment and number of people looking at the comment would be much smaller. Also I would not expect elaborate answer unless it turns out to be very different case from generic one.